# Obtaining weighted random graphs with degree preserving randomisation in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I have a weighted network in which nodes are highly interconnected (250 nodes where 90% of the nodes have degree = 249). The connections are weighted with a normalised index that goes from 0 to 1, where 1 means a strong connection and values close to 0 identify weak connections. The weight distribution of the network is right-skewed and follows a power law, with most edges having proximity close to 0.

I am using degree-preserving randomisation tests in order to compare the network-level characteristics to the distribution of the same characteristics extracted from the randomised graphs. I have implemented a degree-preserving randomisation of the following form:

```
#Obtain the degree distribution to be preserved in the randomised networks
gdegree <- degree(g)

#Generate 1000 random networks with the same degree distribution as g
g.random <- vector('list', 1000)
g.random.degree <- array(dim = c(1000,vcount(g)))

for(i in 1:1000){
  g.random[[i]] <- sample_degseq(gdegree)
  g.random.degree[i,] <- degree(g.random[[i]])
}
```

However, the randomised networks resulting from the code above are unweighted.

Is there a way to obtain weighted random networks using degree preserving randomisation? And secondly, is there a statistical test I can perform in order to select the "significant" connections (those that are observed consistently both in the empirical network and randomised networks)?